# sed -i command for in-place editing to work with both GNU sed and BSD/OSX

Tags: macos, sed, gnu, inplace-editing

I've got a makefile (developed for `gmake` on Linux) that I'm attempting to port to MacOS, but it seems like `sed` doesn't want to cooperate. What I do is use `GCC` to autogenerate dependency files, and then tweak them a bit using `sed`. The relevant portion of the `makefile`:

```bash
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
  $(CPPC) -MM -MD $< -o $@
  sed -i 's|\(.*\)\.o:|$(OBJ_DIR)/\1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/\1.d $(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/\1_utest.o:|' $@
```

While this runs with no trouble under GNU/Linux, I get errors like the following when attempting to build on MacOS:

```bash
sed: 1: "test/obj/equipmentConta ...": undefined label 'est/obj/equipmentContainer_utest.d'
sed: 1: "test/obj/dice_utest.d": undefined label 'est/obj/dice_utest.d'
sed: 1: "test/obj/color-string_u ...": undefined label 'est/obj/color-string_utest.d'
```

It would seem like `sed` is chopping off a character, but I can't see the solution.

Comment: May be, [BashX](https://github.com/reduardo7/bashx) project can help to you with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[OS X `sed`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) handles the `-i` argument differently to the [Linux](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed) version.

You can generate a command that might "work" for both by adding `-e` in this way:

```bash
#      vv
sed -i -e 's|\(.*\)\.o:|$(OBJ_DIR)/\1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/\1.d $(TEST_OBJ_DIR)/\1_utest.o:|' $@
```

OS X `sed -i` interprets the next thing after the `-i` as a file extension for a **backup copy** of the in-place edit.  (The Linux version only does this if there is no space between the `-i` and the extension.) **Obviously a side affect of using this is that you will get a backup file with `-e` as an extension, which you may not want.** Please refer to other answers to this question for more details, and cleaner approaches that can be used instead.

The behaviour you see is because OS X `sed` consumes the `s|||` as the extension (!) then interprets the *next* argument as a command - in this case it begins with `t`, which `sed` recognizes as a branch-to-label command expecting the target label as an argument - hence the error you see.

If you create a file `test` you can reproduce the error:

```bash
$ sed -i 's|x|y|' test
sed: 1: "test": undefined label 'est'
```

Comment: I think if POSIXLY_CORRECT or (older) POSIX_ME_HARDER is defined in the environment, the same behavior can be expected.

Comment: The proper fix for OSX is to have an empty argument to `-i` but then again this is not compatible with Linux sed. )-: Maybe use Perl instead? `perl -pi -e 's|x|y|g' file`

Comment: @TimPost: [`-i` is not a POSIX-compliant option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), so these environment variables don't apply.

Answer (score 62):

Actually, doing

```bash
sed -i -e "s/blah/blah/" files
```

doesn't do what you expect in MacOS either. Instead it creates backup files with `-e` extension.

The proper command for MacOS is

```bash
sed -i "" -e "s/blah/blah/" files
```

On Linux, remove the space between `-i` and `""` (see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813278/1092815))

```bash
sed -i"" -e "s/blah/blah/" files
```

Comment: Right but your answer doesn't work for Linux which is the main issue: needs to work for both. Using -i -e it's still possible to delete -e extension files.

Comment: I suppose for generous definitions of 'working' that is the case.  It's a clever hack, but it produces extra files.  Urkle's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: **WARNING** if you try to find all files with the -e file extension and delete them with something like `find . -type f | grep "-e$" | xargs rm` you will delete all your files. Need to use `"\-e"` and even then run it without the pipe to `xargs rm` first.

Comment: @JamesRobinson, just use `find . -name "*-e" -delete`. Always run without the `-delete` flag first though just to confirm what you're about to delete.

Comment: It appears that the space in `-i ""` needs to be removed to make it work also on Linux: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14813278/15690

Comment: This solution works on OS X, but not on Linux because of the space after the -i.

Comment: `sed -i"" -e "s/blah/blah/" files` commands helps me and it works fine on GitLab-CI

Answer (score 47):

The currently accepted answer is flawed in two very important ways.

1. With BSD sed (the OSX version), the `-e` option is interpreted as
   a file extension and therefore creates a backup file with a `-e`
   extension.
2. Testing for the darwin kernel as suggested is not a reliable
   approach to a cross platform solution since GNU or BSD sed could 
   be present on any number of systems.

A much more reliable test would be to simply test for the `--version` option which is only found in the GNU version of sed.

```bash
sed --version >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Once the correct version of sed is determined, we can then execute the command in its proper syntax.

GNU sed syntax for -i option:

```bash
sed -i -- "$@"
```

BSD sed syntax for -i option:

```bash
sed -i "" "$@"
```

Finally put it all together in a cross platform function to execute an in place edit sed commend:

```bash
sedi () {
    sed --version >/dev/null 2>&1 && sed -i -- "$@" || sed -i "" "$@"
}
```

Example usage:

```bash
sedi 's/old/new/g' 'some_file.txt'
```

This solution has been tested on OSX, Ubuntu, Freebsd, Cygwin, CentOS, Red Hat Enterprise, & Msys.

Comment: If you'd like to combine this with `find`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8489394/25427)

Comment: excellent working on mac el capitan, and ubuntu 17 desktop & server

Comment: Not working with `sed (GNU sed) 4.7` in Ubuntu 20.04.1 docker image. Removing `--` works.

Answer (score 21):

[martin clayton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321958/45375) provides a good explanation of the problem<sup>[1]</sup>, but his solution - as he states - has a potentially unwanted side effect.

Here are **side-effect-free solutions**:

*Caveat*: Solving the `-i` syntax problem alone, as below, may not be enough, because there are many other differences between GNU `sed` and BSD/macOS `sed` (for a comprehensive discussion, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine).

---

#### Workaround with `-i`: Create a backup file *temporarily*, then clean it up:

With a *non-empty* suffix (backup-file filename extension) option-argument (a value that is *not the empty string*), you *can* use `-i` in a way that works with both BSD/macOS `sed` and GNU `sed`, by *directly appending the suffix to the `-i` option*.

This can be utilized to create a backup file *temporarily* that you can clean up right away:

```bash
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' file && rm file.bak
```

Obviously, if you do want to keep the backup, simply omit the `&& rm file.bak` part.

---

#### Workaround that is POSIX-compliant, using a temporary file and `mv`:

If only a *single* file is to be edited in-place, **the `-i` option can be *bypassed*** to avoid the incompatibility.

If you restrict your `sed` script and other options to [POSIX-compliant features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), the following is a **fully portable** solution (note that **`-i` is *not* POSIX-compliant**).

```bash
sed 's/foo/bar' file > /tmp/file.$$ && mv /tmp/file.$$ file
```

- This command simply writes the modifications to a temporary file and, if the `sed` command succeeds (`&&`), replaces the original file with the temporary one.

  - If you do want to keep the original file as a backup, add another `mv` command that renames the original first.
- *Caveat*: Fundamentally, this is what `-i` does too, except that it tries to preserve permissions and extended attributes (macOS) of the original file; however, if the original file is a *symlink*, both this solution and `-i` will replace the symlink with a *regular file*.
  <sup>See the bottom half of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375) of mine for details on how `-i` works.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] For a more in-depth explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864004/45375) of mine.</sup>

Comment: The 'workaround' here is by far the best solution (simplest/most-lightweight/most-posixly). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/) is about a slightly different problem, but includes good discussion of the same `-i` issue.

Comment: Thanks, @NormanGray. Within the given constraints (1 input file only, no preservation of permissions, creation date, extended attributes), that's true.

Comment: Workaround 2 is by far the simplest.  It's also the safest — the in place edit is subject to failure and you've lost the original.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree that the `sed -i.bak ... file && rm file.bak` solution is the simplest and best addresses the original question, so I've moved it to now show as the 1st workaround (and I've removed the numbering to avoid confusion). However, with the POSIX-compliant workaround, given the use of `&&` to only replace the original if `sed` reports success, what problems do you see? I suppose a lack of permissions to replace the original could result in `mv` failing, which would be unpleasant, but you wouldn't lose the original.

Comment: Agreed that the POSIX-compliant solution also works well — and works on platforms like Solaris, AIX or HP-UX where the local `sed` (probably) doesn't support `-i` at all.  So, of the solutions actually using `-i`, the `sed -i.bak …"$file" && rm -f "$file.bak"` solution is best, and the solution not using `-i` at all also has merits. (All the solutions become problematic if the original file is itself a symlink, or if it has multiple links. And permissions/ownership can be a problem when you move/remove files, but that probably applies to the solutions using `-i` too.)

Answer (score 14):

This isn't quite an answer to the question, but one can get linux-equivalent behavior through

```bash
brew install gnu-sed

# Add to .bashrc / .zshrc
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

(previously there was a `--with-default-names` option to `brew install gnu-sed` but that has recently been removed)

Comment: This is definitely the quickest solution for me.

Comment: `brew install gnu-sed` will install `sed` as `gsed`, so you don't need to think about the previous scripts written with OSX's sed.

Comment: I did try with updated `--with-default-names`, only noticed it after opening a new term window, and with `sed --version`, etc.

Comment: Perhaps `hash -r` after install will help :)

Comment: This isn't a workable solution _if_ it is for the general populace.  Programmers may be OK with having to install software to get stuff working, but general users won't.  Since the context of the question is programming and makefiles (broken makefiles IMO, but that's a different discussion), this is potentially a solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler reasonable point, though this is a site for *programmers* and I doubt non-programmers are going to be dealing with `sed`

Answer (score 11):

I came across this issue as well and thought of the following solution:

```bash
darwin=false;
case "`uname`" in
  Darwin*) darwin=true ;;
esac

if $darwin; then
  sedi="/usr/bin/sed -i ''"
else
  sedi="sed -i"
fi

$sedi 's/foo/bar/' /home/foobar/bar
```

Works for me ;-), YMMV

I work in a multi-OS team where ppl build on Windows, Linux and OS X. Some OS X users complained because they got another error - they had the GNU port of sed installed so I had to specify the full path.

Comment: That creates a bar'' backup file for me. But not when writing out the command directly in terminal. Can't really figure out why.

Comment: I had to use eval. eval "$sedi 's/foo/bar/' /home/foobar/bar". This was only tested on os x.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, I've fixed the problem with the " being generated, better than the `eval` solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've corrected the solution posted by @thecarpy:

Here's a proper cross-platform solution for `sed -i`:

```bash
sedi() {
  case $(uname) in
    Darwin*) sedi=('-i' '') ;;
    *) sedi='-i' ;;
  esac

  LC_ALL=C sed "${sedi[@]}" "$@"
}
```

Comment: @masimplo almost the same as `sed -i` on linux, most things are supported, you'd have to dig into the manuals to see where they differ

Comment: Promising, but here's no reason to use `LC_ALL=C` unless you explicitly need to ignore the current locale's character encoding and treat each _byte_ as a character.

Comment: And while using a `bash` array to pass dynamically constructed arguments,  as you do, is generally more robust, there's nothing actually wrong with @thecarpy's answer (except that it would be better to test what implementation the `sed` binary is rather than to test the _host platform_).

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using `sed -i` when writing scripts and i came up with simple solution:

```
printf '%s' "$(sed 's/foo/bar' file)" > file
```

much compatible and is POSIX-compliant. It is doing pretty much the same as `sed -i`, but this one does not create temp files, it directly redirect the changes to file.

As a noob idk what's the **cons** of doing this, the only matters is "It works"