# Replace whole line containing a string using Sed

Tags: string, shell, sed

I have a text file which has a particular line something like

```
sometext sometext sometext TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED sometext sometext sometext
```

I need to replace the whole line above with

```
This line is removed by the admin.
```

The search keyword is `TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED`

I need to write a shell script for this. How can I achieve this using `sed`?

Answer (score 651, accepted):

You can use the *change* command to replace the entire line, and the `-i` flag to make the changes in-place. For example, using GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin.' /tmp/foo
```

Comment: Note that you need a space before the c\. I've just edited to add this.

Comment: @MarcusDowning GNU sed does *not* require the space; it works just fine as originally posted. If your particular sed requires the space, then by all means note which sed is incompatible and add the necessary invocation as a comment. However, please don't change working code in an accepted answer.

Comment: I found the \ after c is not irreplacable. without it the whole command can run perfectly. It was added here to increase readability?

Comment: There is a trouble with " c " command, it can change only 1 line. So if you have multiple lines need to be changed, it will convert it into 1 line.

Comment: How can I use a variable instead of the text "This..."? If I replace it by $variable, it does not print its content but the variable name.

Comment: @Steven That is a separate question, even if it's related. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I figured it out already. It was a question of escaping. Not sure if I will open a new one. There have been enough resources out there :) @CodeGnome

Comment: Getting "sed: 1: "/tmp/foo": invalid command code f" on OS X +zsh.

Comment: There is a problem with `c\ ` when followed directly by a variable: `…c\$VAR…` The backslash will escape the dollar. In this case I (bash/sed on Ubuntu 15.10) had to write `…c\\$VAR…`

Comment: `sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\'"$var" /tmp/foo`

Comment: on a mac use: `sed -i '' '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin.' /tmp/foo` ; (when the first param is blank it edits in-file, otherwise creates a backup)

Comment: In my experience with sed you need the s sed command together with the -i flag to substitute in place. `sed -i 's/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin./' /tmp/foo`

Comment: This is working in my ubuntu machine, but not in my macbook.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Mac. Used the following: sed -i '' "s/Text to replace.*/New text/" index.md

Comment: Note that -i can't be used with standard in.

Comment: This doesn't work when combined with exit code q for e.g. "/^company=/ c\\$line; t; q42" file.txt || echo "Failed to replace". Any idea?

Comment: sed allows for other chars to define delimiter, so for example one can use '|' instead of '\' - this does not get interpreted as escape then, so `c|$VAR` is fine

Answer (score 213):

You need to use wildcards (`.*`) before and after to replace the whole line:

```
sed 's/.*TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED.*/This line is removed by the admin./'
```

Comment: Thank you, got mine working: sed 's/.*<expression>.*/<expression>SE_LABEL = ABC<expression>/g' MYR2.xml > test.txt

Comment: This is working on Mac OS X Yosemite with the exception that I am using the -i and -e flags as follows: `sed -i -e "s/.*search_string.*/Replacement_line/' file_being_searched.txt`

Comment: @KentJohnson I think you have mismatched quotes in your command.

Comment: @MBarnett you are right, I should have two double quotes there.

Comment: Just for the full info. To make it inplace one can add `-i` option

Comment: Getting a `sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code f` in regard to the file at the end of the line.

Comment: The same as above, but with the file `variables.tf` at the end.  I ended up finding another solution anyway.  Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

The Answer above:

```
sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\This line is removed by the admin.' /tmp/foo
```

Works fine if the replacement string/line is not a variable.

The issue is that on Redhat 5 the `\` after the `c` escapes the `$`. A double `\\` did not work either (at least on Redhat 5).

Through hit and trial, I discovered that the `\` after the `c` is redundant if your replacement string/line is only a single line. So I did not use `\` after the `c`, used a variable as a single replacement line and it was joy.

The code would look something like:

```
sed -i "/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c $REPLACEMENT_TEXT_STRING" /tmp/foo
```

Note the use of double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: you can still use single quotes like this:
sed -i '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c '"$VARIABLE"'' /tmp/foo

Comment: This variation worked on Ubuntu/Debian: `sed -i "/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\\$REPLACEMENT_TEXT_STRING" /tmp/foo`

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer did not work for me for several reasons:

- my version of sed does not like `-i` with a zero length extension
- the syntax of the `c\` command is weird and I couldn't get it to work
- I didn't realize some of my issues are coming from unescaped slashes

So here is the solution I came up with which I think should work for most cases:

```
function escape_slashes {
    sed 's/\//\\\//g' 
}

function change_line {
    local OLD_LINE_PATTERN=$1; shift
    local NEW_LINE=$1; shift
    local FILE=$1

    local NEW=$(echo "${NEW_LINE}" | escape_slashes)
    # FIX: No space after the option i.
    sed -i.bak '/'"${OLD_LINE_PATTERN}"'/s/.*/'"${NEW}"'/' "${FILE}"
    mv "${FILE}.bak" /tmp/
}
```

So the sample usage to fix the problem posed:

```
change_line "TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED" "This line is removed by the admin." yourFile
```

Answer (score 10):

All of the answers provided so far assume that you know something about the text to be replaced which makes sense, since that's what the OP asked. I'm providing an answer that assumes you know nothing about the text to be replaced and that there may be a separate line in the file with the same or similar content that you do not want to be replaced. Furthermore, I'm assuming you know the line number of the line to be replaced.

The following examples demonstrate the removing or changing of text by specific line numbers:

```bash
# replace line 17 with some replacement text and make changes in file (-i switch)
# the "-i" switch indicates that we want to change the file. Leave it out if you'd
#   just like to see the potential changes output to the terminal window.
# "17s" indicates that we're searching line 17
# ".*" indicates that we want to change the text of the entire line
# "REPLACEMENT-TEXT" is the new text to put on that line
# "PATH-TO-FILE" tells us what file to operate on
sed -i '17s/.*/REPLACEMENT-TEXT/' PATH-TO-FILE

# replace specific text on line 3
sed -i '3s/TEXT-TO-REPLACE/REPLACEMENT-TEXT/'
```

Answer (score 4):

**for manipulation of config files**

i came up with this solution inspired by [skensell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262057/1262663)

`configLine [searchPattern] [replaceLine] [filePath]`

it will:

- create the file if not exists
- replace the whole line (all lines) where *searchPattern* matched
- add *replaceLine* on the end of the file if pattern was not found

Function:

```
function configLine {
  local OLD_LINE_PATTERN=$1; shift
  local NEW_LINE=$1; shift
  local FILE=$1
  local NEW=$(echo "${NEW_LINE}" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
  touch "${FILE}"
  sed -i '/'"${OLD_LINE_PATTERN}"'/{s/.*/'"${NEW}"'/;h};${x;/./{x;q100};x}' "${FILE}"
  if [[ $? -ne 100 ]] && [[ ${NEW_LINE} != '' ]]
  then
    echo "${NEW_LINE}" >> "${FILE}"
  fi
}
```

the crazy exit status magic comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145797/1262663

Answer (score 3):

To do this without relying on any GNUisms such as `-i` without a parameter or `c` without a linebreak:

```sh
sed '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/c\
This line is removed by the admin.
' infile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile infile
```

In this (POSIX compliant) form of the command

```
c\
text
```

*`text`* can consist of one or multiple lines, and linebreaks that should become part of the replacement have to be escaped:

```sh
c\
line1\
line2
s/x/y/
```

where `s/x/y/` is a new sed command after the pattern space has been replaced by the two lines

```
line1
line2
```

Answer (score 2):

In my makefile I use this:

```
@sed -i '/.*Revision:.*/c\'"`svn info -R main.cpp | awk '/^Rev/'`"'' README.md
```

PS: **DO NOT** forget that the -i changes actually the text in the file... so if the pattern you defined as "Revision" will change, you will also change the pattern to replace.

Example output:

> #### Abc-Project written by John Doe
>
> Revision: 1190

So if you set the pattern "Revision: 1190" it's obviously not the same as you defined them as "Revision:" only...

Answer (score 2):

```
bash-4.1$ new_db_host="DB_HOSTNAME=good replaced with 122.334.567.90"
bash-4.1$ 
bash-4.1$ sed -i "/DB_HOST/c $new_db_host" test4sed
vim test4sed
'
'
'
DB_HOSTNAME=good replaced with 122.334.567.90
'
```

it works fine

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for solutions using `sed`, but if that's not a hard requirement then there is another option which might be a wiser choice.

The accepted answer suggests `sed -i` and describes it as replacing the file in-place, but `-i` doesn't really do that and instead does the equivalent of `sed pattern file > tmp; mv tmp file`, preserving ownership and modes. This is not ideal in many circumstances. In general I do not recommend running `sed -i` non-interactively as part of an automatic process--it's like setting a bomb with a fuse of an unknown length. Sooner or later it will blow up on someone.

To actually edit a file "in place" and replace a line matching a pattern with some other content you would be well served to use an actual text editor. This is how it's done with `ed`, the standard text editor.

```
printf '%s\n' '/TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED/' d i 'This line is removed by the admin' . w q | \
ed -s /tmp/foo > /dev/null
```

Note that this only replaces the *first* matching line, which is what the question implied was wanted. This is a material difference from most of the other answers.

That disadvantage aside, there are some advantages to using `ed` over `sed`:

- You can replace the match with one or multiple lines without any extra effort.
- The replacement text can be arbitrarily complex without needing any escaping to protect it.
- Most importantly, the original file is opened, modified, and saved. A copy is not made.

#### How it works

How it works:

- printf will use its first argument as a format string and print each of its other arguments using that format, effectively meaning that each argument to printf becomes a line of output, which is all sent to `ed` on stdin.
- The first line is a regex pattern match which causes ed to move its notion of "the current line" forward to the first line that matches (if there is no match the current line is set to the last line of the file).
- The next is the `d` command which instructs `ed` to delete the entire current line.
- After that is the `i` command which puts `ed` into insert mode;
- after that all subsequent lines entered are written to the current line (or additional lines if there are any embedded newlines). This means you can expand a variable (e.g. `"$foo"`) containing multiple lines here and it will insert all of them.
- Insert mode ends when `ed` sees a line consisting of `.`
- The `w` command writes the content of the file to disk, and
- the `q` command quits.
- The `ed` command is given the `-s` switch, putting it into silent mode so it doesn't echo any information as it runs,
- the file to be edited is given as an argument to `ed`,
- and, finally, stdout is thrown away to prevent the line matching the regex from being printed.

Some Unix-like systems may (inappropriately) ship without an `ed` installed, but may still ship with an `ex`; if so you can simply use it instead. If have `vim` but no `ex` or `ed` you can use `vim -e` instead. If you have only standard `vi` but no `ex` or `ed`, complain to your sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat find_replace | while read pattern replacement ; do
sed -i "/${pattern}/c ${replacement}" file    
done
```

find_replace file contains 2 columns, c1 with pattern to match, c2 with replacement, the sed loop replaces each line conatining one of the pattern of variable 1

Comment: No, this is wrong on several counts. Run `sed` once with a script file containing all the replacements you want to perform. Running `sed -i` on the same file repeatedly is a horrible antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

To replace whole line containing a specified string with **the content of that line**

Text file:

```
Row: 0 last_time_contacted=0, display_name=Mozart, _id=100, phonebook_bucket_alt=2
Row: 1 last_time_contacted=0, display_name=Bach, _id=101, phonebook_bucket_alt=2
```

Single string:

```
$ sed 's/.* display_name=\([[:alpha:]]\+\).*/\1/'
output:
100
101
```

Multiple strings delimited by white-space:

```
$ sed 's/.* display_name=\([[:alpha:]]\+\).* _id=\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1 \2/'
output:
Mozart 100
Bach 101
```

Adjust regex to meet your needs

[:alpha] and [:digit:]
are [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sed -i <extension> 's/.*<Line to be replaced>.*/<New line to be added>/'
```

An example is:

```
sed -i .bak -e '7s/.*version.*/      version = "4.33.0"/'
```

- `-i`: The extension for the backup file after the replacement. In this case, it is `.bak`.
- `-e`: The sed script. In this case, it is `'7s/.*version.*/      version = "4.33.0"/'`. If you want to use a sed file use the `-f` flag
- `s`: The line number in the file to be replaced. In this case, it is `7s` which means line 7.

**Note**:

If you want to do a recursive find and replace with `sed` then you can `grep` to the beginning of the command:

```
grep -rl --exclude-dir=<directory-to-exclude> --include=\*<Files to include> "<Line to be replaced>" ./ | sed -i <extension> 's/.*<Line to be replaced>.*/<New line to be added>/'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as similar to above one..

```
sed 's/[A-Za-z0-9]*TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED.[A-Za-z0-9]*/This line is removed by the admin./'
```

Comment: That changes `FOO=TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED` to `FOO=This line ...` so does not meet the specification.

Comment: Yes.. Our requirement is to replace entire line with 'This line is removed by the admin.' if we found the key pattren 'TEXT_TO_BE_REPLACED'. The above command is satisfying. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.. @Jens

Comment: @AnnapureddyHari this answer does not work if the text before or after the search string has anything in it besides A-Za-z0-9.  It fails if there is an equals sign, as Jens pointed out.  The "FOO=" portion will remain; you have not replaced the entire line.  This code is short sighted about what might be in the file.  If you mean wildcard, you should put wildcard, as Thor's answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Below command is working for me. Which is working with variables

```
sed -i "/\<$E\>/c $D" "$B"
```

Comment: But my new requirement is to SKIP commented (starts with #) line while replacing.
As we are replacing complete line this will replace commented lines as well and you will end up with duplicate properties.
If anyone has solution for this please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate properties"? To negate matching an address you use `! address`.

Answer (score -1):

I very often use regex to extract data from files I just used that to replace the  literal quote `\"` with `//` nothing :-)

```
cat file.csv | egrep '^\"([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)' | sed  s/\"//g  | cut -d, -f1 > list.txt
```