# How to find and replace line in a file in Unix?

Tags: file, unix, replace

I have for example this line in my file (note that the numbers after = are every time different):

```
abcd=1234
```

and I need to change it to:

```
abcd=9999
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Man, if anybody help me I will accept his answer, but your answer is not good. I found solution myself just now. I'll post it in my question.

Comment: I honestly don't see how that is any different from mine based on the criteria you specified.

Comment: Adam: Feel free to post an actual answer if you have an answer.  Please don't copy an answer into the question itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace whole line containing a string using Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245144/replace-whole-line-containing-a-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 2):

Try `sed -i.backup -e 's/abcd=.*/abcd=9999/' filename.txt`

Example in `filename.txt`

```
abcd=123
abcd=15652
```

Output as expected:

```
abcd=9999
abcd=9999
```

Note: It has been presented to me that this is the GNU sed, which has some extensions apparently that make it different from the normal sed. I was not aware of this, and I have no means to verify this. If someone has the non-gnu solution, please feel free to edit it in.

Comment: I am assuming a lot here, including that you want to change anything labeled `abcd=` to `abcd=9999`.

Comment: Adam, I literally just ran this. I'm most definitely sure it works.

Comment: If it worked I'd like to accept your answer, but it really doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show how it does not? Maybe a more complete example of what you need processed?

Comment: Tested and works on OS X 10.7 and Ubuntu 13.04. @Adam make sure you get the spaces right. `-i .backup` is not portable, but `-i.backup` is.