# How to check if sed has changed a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sed

I am trying to find a clever way to figure out if the file passed to sed has been altered successfully or not.

Basically, I want to know if the file has been changed or not without having to look at the file modification date.

The reason why I need this is because I need to do some extra stuff if sed has successfully replaced a pattern.

I currently have:

```
    grep -q $pattern $filename
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        sed -i s:$pattern:$new_pattern: $filename
                # DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
    else
        # DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
    fi
```

The above code is a bit expensive and I would love to be able to use some hacks here.

Comment: Any time you are trying to do something "clever", you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell because the world was built with stupid inventions.

Comment: What about writing the changes to a new file, and then diff-ing the original and the generated?
By the way, shouldn't sed always replace the pattern if grep found it before?

Comment: @AlvaroGMJ Yeah that is the idea, if grep found a pattern i know for sure that sed will replace it, so i can do my extra stuff right after it.

Comment: Can `SOME OTHER STUFF` be done with `sed`, too?

Comment: The SOME OTHER STUFF is mostly creating logs. So i am guessing no.

Comment: @breakdown1986 then (unless the "replaced *succesfully*" bit indicates that you think it might fail) I don't see the point in the question: you are already sure that SED will replace the pattern when you enter the IF block, and you are using GREP, which is the faster filter in the UNIX world :) (maybe you can add the -F flag, but usually the differences are not significant). Just check sed's exit value and that's it. If you think SED might fail and corrupt your file, write the output to another file and replace it only after checking the return value.

Comment: `sed`'s exit code does not reflect whether any matches were found.

Comment: Here's a full function to count replacements with `grep` then perform them with `sed`. After much consternation getting to this point, I am very pleased with the result. The screenshot shows the output, which is very nice, as it **shows color matching of each replacement**, counts the **number of lines replaced**, *and* counts the **number of replacements**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61238414/4561887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` instead:

`awk '$0 ~ p { gsub(p, r); t=1} 1 END{ exit (!t) }' p="$pattern" r="$repl`"

I'm ignoring the `-i` feature: you can use the shell do do redirections as necessary.

Sigh.  Many comments below asking for basic tutorial on the shell.  You can use the above command as follows:

```
if awk '$0 ~ p { gsub(p, r); t=1} 1 END{ exit (!t) }' \
        p="$pattern" r="$repl" "$filename" > "${filename}.new"; then
    cat "${filename}.new" > "${filename}"
    # DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
else
    # DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
fi
```

It is not clear to me if "DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE" is the same in each case.  Any similar code in the two blocks should be refactored accordingly.

Comment: You can't do in place modifications using only shell redirection. 

command file > file

doesn't work (file is truncated at the moment the redirection is applied, which happens before the command is started)

Comment: `awk '...' $filename > tmp.txt; mv tmp.txt $filename`. `sed -i` just hides the details of the temp file from you.

Comment: @AlvaroGMJ: you cannot do in-place modifications using `sed -i`, but you certainly can do it with shell redirections.  But you are right, you cannot do it with `cmd file > file`.

Comment: Can you give a full example of the solution using awk? It's not clear what you mean about ignoring the -i feature or what sed has to do with this. Your code as it is doesnt appear to work

Comment: Can you expend this answer ? What is "!t" ? What is "exit" ?

Comment: @NinoLenoska `!t` is "not t".  eg, if `t` is zero, then `!t` is 1.  If `t` is non-zero, `!t` is zero.  `exit` is the function that causes awk to exit.

Comment: `sponge` from `moreutils` can help to avoid the tempfile: `awk ... $filename | sponge $filename`

Comment: I can't believe Kernighan is proud of this

Answer (score 49):

A bit late to the party but for the benefit of others, I found the 'w' flag to be exactly what I was looking for.

```
sed -i "s/$pattern/$new_pattern/w changelog.txt" "$filename"
if [ -s changelog.txt ]; then
    # CHANGES MADE, DO SOME STUFF HERE
else
    # NO CHANGES MADE, DO SOME OTHER STUFF HERE
fi
```

`changelog.txt` will contain each change (ie the changed text) on it's own line.  If there were no changes, `changelog.txt` will be zero bytes.

A really helpful sed resource (and where I found this info) is http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html.

Comment: This overwrites the `changelog.txt` file. Any idea how to append to it instead?

Comment: Not directly, however some out-of-process file manipulation is certainly doable.

Comment: I find the overwriting convenient... After every `sed` I can check without keeping in mind to delete the file.

Comment: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a treasure chest but it's way too long. And every time I re-read it I learn new stuffs.

Comment: In case the reader is unfamiliar with shell quoting rules, maybe point out that the text inside the single quotes will not have any shell variables expanded; regard this as pseudocode.

Comment: Fair call.  Changes made.

Comment: That's not always going to work after the latest edit - I think it would better be `'s:'"$pattern"':'"$new_pattern"':w changelog.txt'` so you still (double) quote shell parameters. Without any quoting at all, the command will break if there is a space or a shell special character in either parameter.

Comment: Yeah, I edited again after actually running the code.  This revision works for me in bash.  I'd actually made the edit before the latest comment from Benjamin W and then found that comment waiting for me.  C'est la vie.

Comment: How to apply this with `/g` flag? I mean, how can I combine the `/w` with the `/g`?

Comment: @pgr Look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97297/how-to-report-sed-in-place-changes), which covers the same topic, but in more detail.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Add `cat changelog.txt >> changes.txt`

Comment: also works with `s/search/replace/ w /dev/stdout` - no need to create temporary files : ) see [the solution by acecilia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808364/10440128)

Comment: @pgr `sed -i "s/a/b/g w /dev/stdout" file`

Answer (score 10):

I believe you may find these GNU sed extensions useful

```
t label

If a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line
was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label; if
label is omitted, branch to end of script.
```

and

```
q [exit-code]

Immediately quit the sed script without processing any more input, except 
that if auto-print is not disabled the current pattern space will be printed. 
The exit code argument is a GNU extension.
```

It seems like exactly what are you looking for.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this

Comment: I too do not understand. Hostmaster could you please explain where do we put this options? I'm running sed within an install script and I need to raise warning if sed doesn't manage to change configuration file.

Comment: How to use `t` and `q` options with `sed` command explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1036918/250399. TLDR: `sed -i 's/orig/repl/; t; q1' file.txt`

Comment: Important: looks like this works only for one-line patterns. For sed-ing a whole file, where the replacement is done somewhere in the middle, after sed parses the first line and the replacement is not found there, it will just print the first line unchanged and exit.

Answer (score 10):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i.bak '/'"$old_pattern"'/{s//'"$new_pattern"'/;h};${x;/./{x;q1};x}' file || echo changed
```

Explanation:

- `/'"$old_pattern"'/{s//'"$new_pattern"'/;h}` if the pattern space (PS) contains the `old pattern`, replace it by the `new pattern` and copy the PS to the hold space (HS).
- `${x;/./{x;q1};x}` on encountering the last line, swap to the HS and test it for the presence of any string. If a string is found in the HS (i.e. a substitution has taken place) swap back to the original PS and exit using the exit code of `1`, otherwise swap back to the original PS and exit with the exit code of `0` (the default).

Answer (score 6):

You can diff the original file with the sed output to see if it changed:

```
sed -i.bak s:$pattern:$new_pattern: "$filename"
if ! diff "$filename" "$filename.bak" &> /dev/null; then
  echo "changed"
else
  echo "not changed"
fi
rm "$filename.bak"
```

Comment: Is `diff` going to be less expensive than the `grep` he's trying to replace?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the solution, but I think doing a diff on each file i am gonna search through might be a bit cpu intensive. What do you think ?

Comment: I think so too, this is not really efficient

Comment: `diff` shows you what is different. If you just want to know if there is any difference `cmp` is sufficient. Also `[ $? -ne 0]` is useless. Just put the command into the `if` condition: `if cmp "$filename" "$filename".bak; then`.

Answer (score 5):

In macos I just do it as follows:

```bash
changes=""
changes+=$(sed -i '' "s/$to_replace/$replacement/g w /dev/stdout" "$f")
if [ "$changes" != "" ]; then
  echo "CHANGED!"
fi
```

I checked, and this is faster than `md5`, `cksum` and `sha` comparisons

Comment: limitation: can handle only one substitution. so this does not work: `sed -i 's,a,b, w /dev/stdout ; s,b,a, w /dev/stdout' input.txt`. see [my workaround](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372589/877276)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `s/foo/bar/;t;q8` is that is quits after the first line. To set a proper exit code for multi-line or multi-substitution situations you can use the following:

```bash
sed -i "s/foo/bar/w /dev/stdout" dir/file.txt | grep -q .
echo $?
```

which uses `-i` to change the file in-place, the `w` command to send the successful substitutions to `/dev/stdout`, then we read that with `grep .` to see if output is empty. This returns an exit code of `1` when no match is found, and `0` when substitutions have been made. Use this in conjunction with `set -e` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a old question and using awk instead of sed is perhaps the best idea, but if one wants to stick with sed, an idea is to use the -w flag. The file argument to the w flag only contains the lines with a match. So, we only need to check that it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` to tell if it *has* changed a file; instead, use `grep` to tell if it *is going to* change a file, then use `sed` to actually change the file. Notice the single line of `sed` usage at the *very end* of the Bash function below:

```
# Usage: `gs_replace_str "regex_search_pattern" "replacement_string" "file_path"`
gs_replace_str() {
    REGEX_SEARCH="$1"
    REPLACEMENT_STR="$2"
    FILENAME="$3"

    num_lines_matched=$(grep -c -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME")
    # Count number of matches, NOT lines (`grep -c` counts lines), 
    # in case there are multiple matches per line; see: 
    # https://superuser.com/questions/339522/counting-total-number-of-matches-with-grep-instead-of-just-how-many-lines-match/339523#339523
    num_matches=$(grep -o -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME" | wc -l)

    # If num_matches > 0
    if [ "$num_matches" -gt 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\n${num_matches} matches found on ${num_lines_matched} lines in file"\
                "\"${FILENAME}\":"
        # Now show these exact matches with their corresponding line 'n'umbers in the file
        grep -n --color=always -E "$REGEX_SEARCH" "$FILENAME"
        # Now actually DO the string replacing on the files 'i'n place using the `sed` 
        # 's'tream 'ed'itor!
        sed -i "s|${REGEX_SEARCH}|${REPLACEMENT_STR}|g" "$FILENAME"
    fi
}
```

Place that in your ~/.bashrc file, for instance. Close and reopen your terminal and then use it.

Usage:

```
gs_replace_str "regex_search_pattern" "replacement_string" "file_path"
```

Example: replace `do` with `bo` so that "doing" becomes "boing" (I know, we should be fixing spelling errors not creating them :) ):

```
$ gs_replace_str "do" "bo" test_folder/test2.txt 

9 matches found on 6 lines in file "test_folder/test2.txt":
1:hey how are you doing today
2:hey how are you doing today
3:hey how are you doing today
4:hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today  hey how are you doing today
5:hey how are you doing today
6:hey how are you doing today?
$SHLVL:3
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image]

### References:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/339522/counting-total-number-of-matches-with-grep-instead-of-just-how-many-lines-match/339523#339523
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/580328#580328

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -sple '$replaced++ if s/$from/$to/g;
                END{if($replaced != 0){ print "[Info]: $replaced replacement done in $ARGV(from/to)($from/$to)"}
                else {print "[Warning]: 0 replacement done in $ARGV(from/to)($from/$to)"}}' -- -from="FROM_STRING" -to="$DESIRED_STRING" </file/name>
```

Example:
The command will produce the following output, stating the number of changes made/file.

```
perl -sple '$replaced++ if s/$from/$to/g;
END{if($replaced != 0){ print "[Info]: $replaced replacement done in $ARGV(from/to)($from/$to)"}
else {print "[Warning]: 0 replacement done in $ARGV(from/to)($from/$to)"}}' -- -from="timeout" -to="TIMEOUT" *
[Info]: 5 replacement done in main.yml(from/to)(timeout/TIMEOUT)
[Info]: 1 replacement done in task/main.yml(from/to)(timeout/TIMEOUT)
[Info]: 4 replacement done in defaults/main.yml(from/to)(timeout/TIMEOUT)
[Warning]: 0 replacement done in vars/main.yml(from/to)(timeout/TIMEOUT)
```

Note: I have removed `-i` from the above command , so it will not update the files for the people who are just trying out the command. If you want to enable in-place replacements in the file add `-i` after `perl` in above command.

Answer (score 0):

check if sed has changed MANY files

- recursive replace of all files in one directory
- produce a list of all modified files

workaround with two stages: match + replace

```sh
g='hello.*world'
s='s/hello.*world/bye world/g;'
d='./' # directory of input files
o='modified-files.txt'

grep -r -l -Z -E "$g" "$d" | tee "$o" | xargs -0 sed -i "$s"
```

the file paths in `$o` are zero-delimited

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo hi > abc.txt
$ sed "s/hi/bye/g; t; q1;" -i abc.txt && (echo "Changed") || (echo "Failed")
Changed
$ sed "s/hi/bye/g; t; q1;" -i abc.txt && (echo "Changed") || (echo "Failed")
Failed
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036912/how-do-i-get-the-exit-status-when-using-the-sed-command/1036918#1036918