# How to check if the sed command replaced some string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

This command replaces the old string with the new one if the one exists.

```
sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$source_filename" > $dest_filename
```

How can I check if the replacement happened ? (or how many times happened ?)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144158/how-to-check-if-sed-has-changed-a-file

Comment: `diff $source_filename $dest_filename` should anwser your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not the right tool if you need to count the substitution, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) will fit better your needs :

```
awk -v OLD=foo -v NEW=bar '
    ($0 ~ OLD) {gsub(OLD, NEW); count++}1
    END{print count " substitutions occured."}
' "$source_filename"
```

This latest solution counts only the number of lines substituted. The next snippet counts all substitutions with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). This one has the advantage to be clearer than `awk` and we keep the syntax of `sed` substitution :

```
OLD=foo NEW=bar perl -pe '
    $count += s/$ENV{OLD}/$ENV{NEW}/g;
    END{print "$count substitutions occured.\n"}
' "$source_filename"
```

### Edit

Thanks to [william](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2005672/william) who had found the `$count += s///g` trick to count the number of substitutions (even or not on the same line)

Comment: did you tried this ? when I run this on my file it prints the whole file in the console, I just want to count how many times the 'foo' is replaced with 'bar'

Comment: `sed` print to STDOUT (terminal) too by default. Remove the number `1` if you don't want to print, but that makes no sense to substitute and not printing and redirecting to a new file !

Comment: I think OP also states `how many times happened`. Not just in how many lines but how many substitutions made. Both awk and perl answer only count # of lines substituted.

Comment: In perl try `$count += s/$ENV{OLD}/$ENV{NEW}/g;` (tested in 5.10)

Comment: Removed forgotten `&& $count++`

Comment: `sed` can actually be used right for what the OP wants, and this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144158/how-to-check-if-sed-has-changed-a-file) anyway.

Comment: you could have used the `count +=` with your awk version too... `($0 ~ OLD){a=gsub(OLD,NEW); count+=a}1`

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should count the total number of substitutions instead of the number of lines where  substitutions took place:

```
awk 'END{print t, "substitutions"} {t+=gsub(old,new)}1' old="foo" new="bar" file
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is free for you to choose other tool, like awk, (as @sputnick suggested), go with other tools. Awk could count how many times the pattern matched.

sed itself cannot count replacement, particularly if you use `/g` flag. however if you want to stick to `sed` and know the replacement times there is possibilities:

One way is

```
grep -o 'pattern'|wc -l file && sed 's/pattern/rep/g' oldfile > newfile
```

you could also do it with **tee**

```
cat file|tee >(grep -o 'pattern'|wc -l)|(sed 's/pattern/replace/g' >newfile)
```

see this small example:

```
kent$  cat file
abababababa
aaaaaa
xaxaxa

kent$  cat file|tee >(grep -o 'a'|wc -l)|(sed 's/a/-/g' >newfile)
15

kent$  cat newfile                                               
-b-b-b-b-b-
------
x-x-x-
```

Comment: Linux 5.16, Debian Bookworm/Sid: The output from wc is piped into sed after the output from tee. If I redirect the output from wc into a third file (>), then the count is separate from newfile.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
awk -v s="OLD" -v c="NEW" '{count+=gsub(s,c); }1
END{print count "numbers"}
' opfilename
```

Comment: A short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.