# sed find replace or add if nothing is found

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have the following in my config.txt file.

```
some text
firmware_version 12.3
some more text ...
```

The `sed -i 's/^firmware_version .*/firmware_version 12.4/' /config.txt` command replaces the firmware version but
what I'd like to be able to do is that even if `sed` doesn't find a line occurrence of `"firmware_version .*"` it still adds the new replacement.

In other words if my config.txt file includes the following:

```
some text
some more text ...
```

I'd still like the end result to be

```
some text
firmware_version 12.4
some more text ...
```

I just want to come up with a universal one line command for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Should it detect 'some text' or 'some more text' as the match with no 'firmware_version' in between? Or can 'firmware_version' go at the end if the 'firmware_version' is not found?  Spotting that the firmware version is missing between two lines is probably harder than adding it at the end, though neither is entirely straight-forward.  Could there be other lines between 'some text' and 'some more text' than just 'firmware_version'?

Comment: 'firmware_version' can go to the end if it's not found, and the config file can be completely empty too, so there might be nothing in the config file and 'firmware_version' should still be added if that command is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your responses

I was really looking for an easier and simpler solution and I would expect `sed` to return a different exit status when the searched text doesn't match and then I could decide what to do next.

There are some [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match) on how to make `sed` return a specific code if it doesn't match a criteria, but I couldn't make it work and the manual doesn't mention anything about it (or I may have missed something)

After a little more research I [found](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/154429-exit-status-sed-when-fails.html) not a very neat but an acceptable solution.

```
grep -q '^firmware_version .*' /config.txt && sed -i 's/^firmware_version .*/firmware_version 12.4/' /config.txt || echo 'firmware_version 12.4' >> /config.txt
```

So if grep finds a match then we run the `sed` command otherwise we `echo` the 'firmware_version 12.4' text to config.txt

Answer (score 0):

For non-empty files, this works.  It's a different model, though.  If the 'firmware_version' appears between 'some text' and 'some more text' then delete it.  When you come across 'some more text', insert the firmware version.  It's tricky enough that I put the editing commands into a file named (unoriginally) `sed.script`:

```
/some text/,/some more text/{
/firmware_version .*/d
/some more text/i\
firmware_version 12.4
}
```

Then, given `config-1.txt`:

```
some text
firmware_version 12.3
some more text
```

and `config-2.txt`:

```
some text
some more text
```

you can run the script like:

```
sed -f sed.script config-1.txt
```

and it produces the same output for both inputs:

```
some text
firmware_version 12.4
some more text
```

If the input file is empty, I think it is best handled separately.  This shell script fragment writes the new file to standard output:

```
if [ -s ${config_file} ]
then sed -f sed.script ${config_file}
else echo "firmware_version 12.4"
fi
```

If you want to overwrite the original file and your `sed` supports `-i.bak`, then:

```
if [ -s ${config_file} ]
then sed -i.bak -f sed.script       ${config_file}
else echo "firmware_version 12.4" > ${config_file}
fi
```

Comment: `.*` is unnecessary for `sed`'s delete statement.

Comment: @user1718888 — you are correct, though it is harmless and unlikely to hurt performance measurably.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @sylvian's answer:

- You don't need `.*` for grep since that pattern doesn't enforce anything and grep will return true if it finds a pattern anywhere on a line.
- You can make your `sed` expression DRYer by capturing the key: `sed -i 's/^(firmware_version) .*/\1 12.4/'`
- If you don't care about position, you can drop the grep entirely:

```
sed -i '/^firmware_version/d' config.txt; echo 'firmware_version 12.4' >> config.txt
```

But seriously, `awk` is much better at parsing fields and this is a key/value pair in columns:

```bash
touch config.txt
awk -i inplace \
    -v 'k=firmware_version' \
    -v 'v=12.4' \
    '$1 == k{f=1;$2=v} 1; ENDFILE {if(!f) print k, v}' config.txt
```

(note: `-i inplace` is not entirely portable, if it doesn't work for you, consider `mktemp` or `sponge`)

The `touch` will create an empty file if it doesn't exist (a problem that is not addressed by any of the answers so far).

The awk statement says:

- If the **first** field is **exactly** "firmware_version", set the "found" variable (`f`) to true and set the **second** field to "12.4".
- Print all lines (`1`) (including modified lines).
- If at the end of the file, the match was never found, print a new line with "firmware_version 12.4"

This avoids regex entirely. Since we're looking at fields, we don't need to be concerned about anchors, we won't match words found in other fields and we won't accidentally match keys like "firmware_version_update".

It's concise and reusable (you can just change the variables `k` and `v`) and it avoids using 3 different commands with a true/false chain (which *can* lead to unexpected results).

This also works with empty files, preserves the placement of "firmware_version" (if it exists) and preserves any text *after* the new value such as a comment.

```
firmware_version 12.4      # This comment stays put!
```

See it in action: https://glot.io/snippets/gbrzh99b0p

##### Really tiny edge-case

Awk detects fields using a repeating regex space delimiter by default so it will change a line  with leading whitespace that looks like this:

```
         firmware_version ...
```

If there's a comment marker like `#` before it, that won't matter. This only matters to lines with explicitly whitespace behind the first column.

If for some incredibly insane reason that means something different for your application, then you *would* have to use an anchor and pattern matching and `$1 == k` becomes
`BEGIN {p="^"k} $0 ~ p`.

---

I think @anubhava's answer (also using awk) is a misinterpretation of the problem since "some text" is likely an unknown placeholder (also, it does not handle empty files).

If leading/trailing lines in a block of text are known, then @johnathan-leffler's answer is better. Here's a slightly more legible script:

```
/some text/,/some more text/{
  /^firmware_version /d
  /some more text/ifirmware_version 12.4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do something that just uses `sed` (doesn't involve checking for the line and then taking different action based on whether it exists).

It looks like you don't care about where the `firmware_version` line is inserted, in that case I would suggest printing all lines that do not start with `firmware_version` and then append the `firmware_version 12.4` line to the end:

```
sed -i -n '/^firmware_version /!p;'"\$afirmware_version 12.4" ${config_file}
```

If you *do* want it after `some text`, then use this version instead (print lines that *do not* contain `firmware_version` and then append `firmware_version 12.4` after the line `some text`):

```
sed -i -n '/firmware_version /!p;'"/^some text$/afirmware_version 12.4" ${config_file}
```