# How can I pass correctly the parameter `q` with value 100 to my sed expression?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to understand the answer on [Return code of sed for no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match), but it dos not make any sense the expression `sed '/foo/{s/f/b/;q}; /foo/!{q100}'`. He could just not create a simple example? Why these so many slashes `/`, semicolons `;` and extra pair of `/foo/`.

I am trying to replace the `tr` by `foo` and make sed have the return code `$?` of 100 when its succeeds the operation. I tried this code and does not work.

```
echo "trash"|sed 's/tr/foo/!{q100}'; echo $?
```

Output is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
1
```

How can I pass correctly the parameter `q` with value 100 to my sed expression?

Comment: `q` is a command by itself, not a flag to apply to the `s` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command is wrong; this does the job:

```
$ echo trash | sed '/tr/{ s/tr/foo/; q100 }'
fooash
$ echo $?
100
```

What the sed command does:

```
/tr/ {      # find the tr string, then enter the block
s/tr/foo/;  # replace tr with foo
q100        # exit with 100
}
```

Unfortunately, `sed` is well known to be an encrypted language. All the slashes and semicolons need to be decrypted first with eyeballs. I highly recommend you to follow a good and thorough sed tutorial before stepping into the deep water: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html

Comment: Thanks, but but why it give error when I replace `/` by `@` as in `echo trash | sed '@tr@{ s@tr@foo@; q100 }'`? If I just call `echo trash | sed '/tr/{ s/tr/foo/; q100 }'` with `/` it does work, but not with `@`

Comment: @user this works `echo trash | sed '\@tr@{ s@tr@foo@; q100 }'`. this question is answered in the tutorial i pasted above.