# Why sed is replacing all my file contents?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to insert a /file/path as string at the beginning of the file and have sed returning the code 100, but it is replacing all my files contents:

```
printf "Message\nMessage\nMessage\n" > test.tex;
sed -i "\@^@{ 1s@^@% Message\n@; q100}" test.tex;
cat test.tex;
```

Outputs:

```
% Message
Message
```

If I try to put `1s` on the beginning:

```
sed -i "\1s@^@{ 1s@^@% Message\n@; q100}" test.tex
```

It throws the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unexpected `}'
```

References:

1. [Return code of sed for no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match)
2. [How can I pass correctly the parameter `q` with value 100 to my sed expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575600/how-can-i-pass-correctly-the-parameter-q-with-value-100-to-my-sed-expression)

---

## Update

I just noticed it does not make any sense having the return code as 100, so I can just do

`sed '1s@^@% Message\n@'`

But for curiosity, would this be possible?

## Update 2

The correct output would be:

```
% Message
Message
Message
Message
```

That is, keep the initial 3 files `Message` I added to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed's default behavior if it isn't told to do anything else is to echo each line after running any commands that have been specified for it.  So when you do `sed -i ";" test.tex`, it'll run `;` on line 1, echo the (unchanged) line, and then move to line 2 and repeat the process.  But if you do `sed -i "q" test.tex`, it makes the (total lack of) changes to line 1, echoes it, then runs the `q` command and exits immediately without having a chance to echo all the other lines.

That's what's happening in your code.  To avoid that issue, you should specify a line range over which the `q` command will execute.  `$` is the last line, so:

```
sed -i "\@^@{ 1s@^@% Message\n@;}; $ {q100}" test.tex;
```

Comment: `sed -i "\@^@{ 1s@^@% Message\n@ ;$ q100}"` would probably work too; good explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to insert a line at the beginning of the file, you could try this

```
sed -i -e '1i\% Message' -e '$q100' test.tex
```

The below command instructs sed to insert "%Message" before the first line.

```
-e '1i\% Message'
```

The below command instructs sed to quit with return code 100 after printing the last line.

```
-e '$q100'
```