# Sed deleting xml file contents if !{q100}; return is used

Tags: bash, sed

I have a sed command I wish to run from within a bash script on a large `xml` file.

```
sed -i '/$OLD_IP_ADDRESS/!{q100};  {s/$OLD_GATEWAY/$NEW_GATEWAY/}'   $system_file
```

where , if `$OLD_IP_ADDRESS` is present I substitute `$OLD_GATEWAY` for `$NEW_GATEWAY` (IPs) but `$OLD_IP_ADDRESS` if it is not present then I return `100`

I am using the following from

[Return code of sed for no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match)

as an example

```
kent$  echo "foo" | sed  '/foo/!{q100}; {s/f/b/}'
boo
kent$  echo $?
0
```

However when I run the command it removes the entire body of the `xml` and only leaves me with the header line

I have tried numerous variations of this  but don't understand/see  where I'm blanking the file.

I have searched but cant find info on this so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: The above solution will work for a one line file, for 2 or more lines the solution will always fail unless every line is substituted. Go back to that solution and read on.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  I will investigate an awk alternative

Comment: Also you can't use single quotes if you want the shell to substitute the value of a variable.

Comment: someone needs to post a guide to quotes that you're not allowed to write a shell script without understanding - misuse of quotes is by far the most common source of questions I see! [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (including values of those shell variables) and expected output so we can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As @potong said, you can't use the `q` sed option in a multiline file, because it will ever fail ***unless*** every line has what you are searching for.

If you want to search if something is present or not, you can use `grep` before doing substitutions.

You can do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
if grep -q -e "${OLD_IP_ADDRESS}" "${system_file}"; then
   sed -i -e "s/${OLD_GATEWAY}/${NEW_GATEWAY}/" "${system_file}"
else
   exit 100
fi
```

This piece of code will substitute every first occurrence (`g` option not used) of `${OLD_GATEWAY}` with `${NEW_GATEWAY}` in every line only if `${OLD_IP_ADDRESS}` is present at least once in the file.

If you need a oneliner you can use something like:

```
grep -q -e "${OLD_IP_ADDRESS}" "${system_file}" && sed -i -e "s/${OLD_GATEWAY}/${NEW_GATEWAY}/" "${system_file}"
```

being aware that the exit code will be different from `100`.

Comment: Many Thanks !!!  using#!/bin/bash
if grep -q -e "${OLD_IP_ADDRESS}" "${system_file}"; then
   sed -i -e "s/${OLD_GATEWAY}/${NEW_GATEWAY}/" "${system_file}" old_ip_present=1
else
   old_ip_present=0
fi        i was able to error check on the old_ip_present= part

Comment: Assuming OLD_IP_ADDRESS, etc. are actually IP addresses, you'd need to escape the `.`s` in them and anchor them to avoid false matches.