# Sed substitution with quit giving only first line of file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to substitute `timeout`, and return `1` if the substitution fails.

abc.conf:

```
Title: ABC.conf
timeout : 10
```

sed command and output:

```
$ sed '/timeout/{s/timeout .*/timeout 100/g;Q};q1' abc.conf
$ Title:ABC.conf
```

But, `sed` fails to substitute returned `1`, and in the output I only get the first line of the file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `sed '/timeout .*/,${s//timeout 100/;b};$q1' abc.conf`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return code of sed for no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965073/return-code-of-sed-for-no-match)

Comment: The `q` command tells `sed` to stop processing the file there and then. You have it outside the braces, so it isn't governed by any condition. Therefore, it triggers unconditionally on the first line.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks that worked, can you please explain whats happening here?

Comment: It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966279/3832970) very well.

Comment: Yes it is, very well thanks @WiktorStribiżew