# Replace occurrences of a string in file with different bytes of entropy each

Tags: regex, linux, string, awk, sed

On Linux, I need to programmatically replace placeholder strings such as `<SECRET>` in a `.env` file like this:

```sh
KEY=<SECRET>
ANOTHER_VARIABLE=another-value
# here's a comment
PASSWORD=<SECRET>
```

The caveat is, that each occurrence of this placeholder must be replaced with a *different* instantiation of Base64 encoded randomness - e.g. from OpenSSL, since it's readily available on many Linuxes.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148473/1492145), I tried this with GNU `sed` 4.8:

```sh
sed -i '0,/<SECRET>/ s__'$(openssl rand -base64 42)'_' .env
```

(In the substitution part the alternative delimiter `_` was chosen, because the Base64 encoded bytes can contain `/` or `+` characters and would otherwise clash when inadvertently used as delimiters.)

---

This works for single replacements, one call at a time.

**But sed's return code is always `0`**, even when all occurrences of the regex have been consumed and replaced...

Question: Is there a way to make sed return a non-zero code when placeholders have been exhausted?

(If this can't be done with sed, I'm happy for any solution with awk or similar.)

Comment: Does this <https://stackoverflow.com/q/15965073> answer your question?

Comment: @Quasímodo i've tried this already, but this also didn't work - return codes were still 0.

Comment: i've ended up grep'ing for the placeholder in a while loop before doing the substitution with sed, as @Quasímodo suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `sed`, you could use `grep`:

```
grep '<SECRET>' .env
```

From `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally  the  exit  status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q
>   or --quiet or --silent is
>          used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred.

If the return value is 0, then apply your `sed` command to perform the substitution.

Comment: thanks, this did the trick: simply wrapping the sed substitution in a while condition with grep: `while grep -q '<SECRET>' test; do sed -i '0,/<SECRET>/ s__'$(openssl rand -base64 42)'_' test; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "openssl rand -base64 42" }
    match($0,/<SECRET>/) {
        val = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        close(cmd)
    }
1' file
KEY=hDc3Bw4J9+TUbbhw4cNKda+mDHVRGGrAWUU6LX7aYZnWwDZWyqrmzi3z
ANOTHER_VARIABLE=another-value
# here's a comment
PASSWORD=LzGaB43Mm5mF6tsJnwOLqgeeoTwajH9FNLty9yD22QovadhwWKpr7AP6
```

or if `<SECRET>` can occur multiple times on 1 line then:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { cmd = "openssl rand -base64 42" }
    {
        while ( match($0,/<SECRET>/) ) {
            val = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
            $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            close(cmd)
        }
    }
1' file
KEY=t3/bimGkyPQcjOL6ubV6QmRnPjrvtg4+HvvkuJSnuYCYc+BzOmAWKRV6
ANOTHER_VARIABLE=another-value
# here's a comment
PASSWORD=TKvDbMphOhmhL0/NSQEE2Gs9sFr3Cwt9o3CbOoe9FZPjAR/+m6i4QjcR
```