# sed branching not working on OSX: undefined label

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to adapt the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365284/1236401 that adds control flow to provide match status code:

```sh
cat file.txt | sed 's/1/replaced-it/;tx;q1;:x'
```

It works as expected on Ubuntu and Alpine, but fails on Mac OSX (`11.6`), using any shell.

> sed: 1: "s/1/replaced-it/;tx;q1;:x": undefined label 'x;q1;:x'

All references I could find to `sed` misbehaving on OSX were for in-place file edit, which is not the case here.

Comment: The question has been answered, but for reference, from the POSIX man page: `Command verbs other than {, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another command verb.`. For these commands you can use a new line, or break in to chunks with `-e` (which is also POSIX). "undefined label" is BSD sed accepting `;` in a label, whilst in GNU, the command separator meaning takes precedence (which is a deviation from the standard).

Comment: sed is a great tool for doing simple s/old/new/ substitutions on individual lines but if you have any other text manipulation to do the code to do it will be some combination of clearer, more robust, more portable, and more efficient if you use awk. Idk what that sed incantation does so idk if @triplee's answer is the awk equivalent or not - if it isn't and you add concise, testable sample input and expected output and an `awk` tag we can help you.

Comment: This could be written `sed '/1/{s//replaced-it/;q1}' file` or `sed '/1/!b;s//replace-it/;q1' file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands in sed are separated primarily by newlines.

```
| sed 's/1/replaced-it/
  tx
  q1
  :x
'
```

Alternatively:

```
sed -e 's/1/replaced-it/' -e 'tx' -e 'q1' -e ':x'
```

Additionally `q1` is a GNU sed extension - it's not supported in every `sed`. It has to be removed, refactored, or you have to install GNU `sed`.

Overall, write it in awk, python or perl.

Comment: Still not working for me, both fail with `extra characters at the end of q command`

Comment: `q1` is a gnu extension, it's not supported in normal sed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Awk refactoring.

```
awk '/1/ { sub("1", "replaced-it", $0); replaced=1 } 1
    END { exit 1-replaced }' file.txt
```

Notice also how [the `cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) (with `sed` too, and generally any standard Unix command except annoyingly `tr`).

Comment: `/1/ { sub("1", "replaced-it", $0); replaced=1 }` = `sub(/1/, "replaced-it"){ replaced=1 }`

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, that's a lot prettier.

Answer (score 1):

An AWK equivalent would be:

```
awk '!sub(/1/,"replaced-it") {print; exit 1} 1' file.txt
```

If a substitution is not made successfully: print and exit with a status of 1; otherwise print.