# Replace whole line when match found with sed

Tags: shell, replace, sed, match

I need to replace the whole line with `sed` if it matches a pattern.
For example if the line is 'one two six three four' and if 'six' is there, then the whole line should be replaced with 'fault'.

Comment: Have you considered `grep -v`?

Comment: I realize it's been a couple of years, but you should remember to come back and upvote/accept an answer if it was useful to you --and it looks like there're a few that appear to answer the question correctly.

Answer (score 119):

You can do it with either of these:

```
sed 's/.*six.*/fault/' file     # check all lines
sed '/six/s/.*/fault/' file     # matched lines -> then remove
```

It gets the full line containing `six` and replaces it with `fault`.

Example:

```
$ cat file
six
asdf
one two six
one isix
boo
$ sed 's/.*six.*/fault/'  file
fault
asdf
fault
fault
boo
```

It is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11245501/1983854) to [Replace whole line containing a string using Sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11245144/1983854)

More generally, you can use an expression **`sed '/match/s/.*/replacement/' file`**. This will perform the `sed 's/match/replacement/'` expression in those lines containing `match`. In your case this would be:

```
sed '/six/s/.*/fault/' file
```

---

> What if we have 'one two six eight eleven three four' and we want to
>   include 'eight' and 'eleven' as our "bad" words?

In this case we can use the `-e` for multiple conditions:

```
sed -e 's/.*six.*/fault/' -e 's/.*eight.*/fault/' file
```

and so on.

Or also:

```
sed '/eight/s/.*/XXXXX/; /eleven/s/.*/XXXX/' file
```

Comment: What if we have 'one two six eight eleven three four' and we want to include 'eight' and 'eleven' as our "bad" words? Will s/.*six|eight|eleven.*/fault/g work?

Comment: What if i want to store the changes in the same file?

Comment: @M.M.H.Masud just use `sed -i`. You better use also `sed -i.bak` so the original file gets replaced but also backed up to `file.bak`.

Comment: The `/g` flag is useless here, as there can only ever be a single match on one line, and you only care whether there is one or more matches anyway.

Comment: @tripleee you are right. Something + `.*` will have a unique match per line, if any. Thanks!

Comment: should also explain when to use double quotes for variables IMO

Answer (score 16):

Above answers worked fine for me, just mentioning an alternate way

Match single pattern and replace with a new one:

```
sed -i '/six/c fault' file
```

Match multiple pattern and replace with a new one(concatenating commands):

```
sed -i -e '/one/c fault' -e '/six/c fault' file
```

Answer (score 5):

To replace whole line containing a specified string with **the content of that line**

Text file:

```
Row: 0 last_time_contacted=0, display_name=Mozart, _id=100, phonebook_bucket_alt=2
Row: 1 last_time_contacted=0, display_name=Bach, _id=101, phonebook_bucket_alt=2
```

Single string:

```
$ sed 's/.* display_name=\([[:alpha:]]\+\).*/\1/'
output:
100
101
```

Multiple strings delimited by white-space:

```
$ sed 's/.* display_name=\([[:alpha:]]\+\).* _id=\([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1 \2/'
output:
Mozart 100
Bach 101
```

Adjust regex to meet your needs

[:alpha] and [:digit:]
are [Character Classes and Bracket Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/six/{c\fault' -e ';d}' file
```

or:

```
sed '/six/{c\fault'$'\n'';d}' file
```