# How to delete a particular line from several files in linux?

Tags: html, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have several html files within subfolders which have a redundant link like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../demos.css">
```

I am trying to remove this line from all the html files using the following command in linux:

```
find -name '*.html' -exec sed --in-place=.bak 'demos.css' "{}" ;
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Yes of course I have checked all the solutions on Stackoverflow related to this but most of them are regarding a single file and the rest don't help. What am I doing wrong with this code?

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245144/replace-whole-line-containing-a-string-using-sed

Answer (score 2):

`find` is missing starting path, `sed` is missing `d` command and you need to escape the semi colon in `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -i.bak '/demos\.css/d' '{}' \;
```

Or better:

```
find . -name '*.html' -exec sed -i.bak '/demos\.css/d' '{}' +
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command` -in both cases.

Comment: In the first case I am getting this error several times and in the second one I am getting it only once.

Comment: Still the same error. I don't understand why, it seems alright!

Comment: Yes. Exactly like you posted.

Comment: Ah just realized you don't have `d` command in sed (see updated answer)

Comment: Glad it worked, Sorry for my goof ups, I was paying attention to other options in `find` rather than `sed` command.

Comment: If it worked out, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
for i in `find /www/htmls/ -name "*.html" 2>/dev/null`
do
    sed -i '/demos\.css/d' "$i"
done
```

Comment: Does not give any error but does not change the html files either.

Comment: sorry, escape the "."

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `find /www/htmls/ -name "*.html" 2>/dev/null`
do
    sed -i 's/^demos.css.*//' "$i"
done
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.