# sed match and replace in file except for comments

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to automatically disable logging into SSH via root. I know I can manually edit the file and do so, but I want to disable root login through a Bash script (that I use to initialize my servers).

I haven't used `sed` much, but I think it's what I should used based off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245144/replace-whole-line-containing-a-string-using-sed).

The line I am trying to replace, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, is `PermitRootLogin {any_value}`. The default value of `{any_value}` is `yes` but I would like this to work for any value (on the same line).

I tried the command `sudo sed -i "/PermitRootLogin/c\PermitRootLogin no" /etc/ssh/sshd_config` but this also replaces a random comment that contains the text "PermitRootLogin".

So, I don't want to replace lines that begin with a comment token, `#`.

Here is the relevant parts of the file I am trying to edit (my comments are added with "###"):

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes ### I want to replace this line with "PermitRootLogin no"
StrictModes yes

# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
```

The expected output is:

```
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
```

Then, I tried this: `sed -i "\(^[\# ]\)+/PermitRootLogin/c\PermitRootLogin no" /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

This gives me an error of: `sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unterminated address regex`.

How can I accomplish what I am trying to do? Thank you!

Comment: ...and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed '/^#/!s/PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The pattern `/^#/` matches a line which starts with a comment. The `!` negates the match meaning the subsequent command will be executed on non-comment lines only.

The substitute comment replaces `PermitRootLogin` following by anything `.*` by `PermitRootLogin no`.

Use `-i` once you are sure it works correctly.

Comment: I want to replace all `word` with `newword` except `wordlist`, how?

Comment: I recommend to post a question - if you cannot find the answer. The comments aren't the right place to ask.

Comment: I think my asking is about similar of this question.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
sed -i "s/^[^#]*PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin no/g" file

^: Beginning of line
[^#]*: any character but no #
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/^PermitRootLogin .*/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: i think this one should be answer. why would you care about comment if `PermitRootLogin` is at the beginning of the line. btw, i think change `.*` to `[^#]*` would help since it doesn't replace the trailing comment along with the switch, if any.