# Output of sed in linux won't write to file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sed command find and replace in file and overwrite file doesnt work, it empties the file!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties)

Ok so I've got this:

`sed "s/^/getHtmlBody\(\"\/NmConsole\/Reports\/Workspace\/Virtualization\/WrVMwareHostList\/WrVMwareHostList.asp\?sGroupList=1'/g" out.bat | sed "s/$/\';--\");/g" >out.bat`

And as you can see I'm trying to out into **out.bat** but it isn't working for some reason - nothing gets displayed on the screen but nothing is written to the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: reading from out.dat and writing back into it at the same time?

Comment: This is a [famous pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2BAC8-foo.2BAC8-bar.2BAC8_.3E_file)

Comment: Figures, ha. Works now after making the changes mentioned :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Bash sees "> out.bat" it truncates the file. The file is now empty, so sed doesn't find the beginnings nor ends of any lines and nothing gets put into out.bat

[kojiro's link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2BAC8-foo.2BAC8-bar.2BAC8_.3E_file) and an [SO asnwer by codaddict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171935/8539159) has a nice description plus ways to get around it.