# issues with sed on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I am trying to delete a line on a file that looks like this:

test 1800 IN CNAME mydomain.com.

I am using sed on Mountain Lion and I am trying the following but I keep getting no errors, however the line is not deleted.

```
sed -i -e '/$regex/d' $file
```

or

```
sed -i "" -e '/$regex/d' $file
```

Where the $regex is the expression containing the line mention above and the $file is the name of the file where the line is.

Any help Will be appreciate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac and Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-and-linux)

Comment: See the linked post, -i won't work on BSD sed (which OSX uses).

Comment: BSD `sed` on Lion and Mountain Lion has the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a near duplicate of [Sed command find and replace in file ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901), and the most portable answer is the same as there:

```
sed -e '/$regex/d' $file >$file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
```

...for the reasons, and with the advantages, given there.  When you're concerned about portability, the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) is a great resource, since it describes a common subset of unix commands, which is often frustratingly restricted, but which is pretty reliably present in all the unixes one is likely to come across.

Answer (score 0):

Mountain Lion (v10.8.2) works just fine with `sed -i "" -e '/$regex/d' $file`

```
[Mar 12 17:22] [jnovack@growlithe ~]$ more test.php
<?php
echo "Test php echo 1";
echo "Test echo 2";
?>
[Mar 12 17:22] [jnovack@growlithe ~]$ sed -i "" -e "/php/d" test.php
[Mar 12 17:22] [jnovack@growlithe ~]$ more test.php
echo "Test echo 2";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem, it seems to me, is that you have a shell variable `$regex` which contains the pattern to be searched for and deleted, but your single quotes prevent the shell expanding it.  You likely need to use:

```
sed -i .bak -e "/$regex/d" $file
```

(BSD `sed` on Lion and Mountain Lion supports the `-i` option.  The manual page recommends against a zero-length back-up extension.)

> `-i extension`
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension
>                is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when
>                in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk
>                space is exhausted, etc.