# Shell script/command for replacing a (single) string in multiple files?

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sh

(I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can only find somewhat-similar questions.)

I have bunch of files, some of which contain the string "foobar". I would like to replace, in each of those files, the occurrences of "foobar" with "baz" - in those files, not in new files or streamed anywhere.

I'd like to specify the filenames on the command-line, i.e.

```
[me@myhost:/$] magic_replace "foobar" "baz" file1 file2 file3 etc
```

Comment: Check `sed -i`. For example here you can find a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5171935/1983854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e 's/foo/baz/g' file1 file2
```

or this:

```
for file in $(echo file1 file2); do
    sed -i -e 's/foo/baz/g' $file
done
```

The first one should work if sed accepts multiple input files, check it.

Answer (score 2):

use sed.

```
sed -i 's/foobar/baz/g' file1 file2 file3 etc
```