# Permanently delete a specific last number lines of a file

Tags: bash, sed

I used the following command in the bash to remove the last two lines of bash.bashrc (I added some bad lines) : `sed '69,70d' /etc/bash.bashrc`

But it doesn't delete the lines permanently as I would like.

Comment: I'm using the last version of linuxlint

Comment: `sed -i` : replaces in the file (and thus modifies the file). your `sed '69,70d' /etc/bashrc` just outputs the file minus lines 69,70. `sed -i '69,70d' /etc/bash.bashrc` would do that in (and thus modify) the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is using `head -n -<n>` in combination of `tee`.

Although `head` does not support in place edit which is supported in `sed -i`
, you can accomplish in place edit using `tee` command.

See: [sed command find and replace in file and overwrite file doesn't work, it empties the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties)

```
head -n -2 /etc/bash.bashrc | sudo tee /etc/bash.bashrc >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work to remove the last two lines:

```
sed -n -e :a -e '1,2!{P;N;D;};N;ba' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

And then if you pipe it through `| cat > /etc/bash.bashrc` it will overwrite the file with the new shortened content:

```
sed -n -e :a -e '1,2!{P;N;D;};N;ba' /etc/bash.bashrc | cat > /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: maybe you should use `-i` option. it's implemented in gnu sed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't seem to work. Are there no simpler way to do it?