# Bash - sed command. How to not overwrite old string?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script. The output of this bash script is a config file which I create from a template file. I would like to use a `sed` command where I can specify `###member###` as a match pattern, and `AA` as the replacement. But when I create a new config file with a new replacement `BB`, the old string `AA` is overwritten. I don't want to overwrite that old string `AA`; I just need to add `BB` behind `AA`.

EXAMPLE:

```
members     ###members###

members     aa, bb, cc, ...
```

I don't know if I can achieve this task with the `sed` command.

Comment: What's your actual input and the expected output?

Comment: Did you go through this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties

Comment: what do you already try ?

Comment: My actual input is from my template file where is line members and string for replace ###members###. Output file should looks like members AA. And then i create new config file from my template file and output file should looks like members AA, BB ...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/###members###/{:a;N;/aa/s//&BB/;Ta}' file
```

Look for a line containing `###members###` then append following lines to it until those lines contain `aa` and then append `BB` to `aa`.