# how to use sed to replace a line in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a Podspec and I want to change the version in that file using sed and regex. the line is below

```
s.version  (ignore spaces)  =  (ignore spaces) "x.x.x"
```

What would be the exact sed command to change this version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed command find and replace in file and overwrite file doesnt work, it empties the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties)

Comment: This question is extremely common.  What have you tried? How did it fail?  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: the regex part. see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
~$ sed 's/^\(s.version *= *\)"[^"]*"/\1"a.b.c"/' myfile
```

You can use the `-i` option to modify in place the file.

Comment: i changed it like this : sed 's/^\(*s.version *= *\)"[^"]*"/\1"a.b.c"/' myfile to ignore spaces in the start too. thanks for your answer. it works.