# Use sed to change an entry of a configuration file

Tags: sed

I want to change the following line in /etc/security/limits.conf from

```
#*               soft    core           0
```

to

```
*               soft    core            unlimited
```

to enable core dump.

I tried to use the following sed command but it did nothing:

```
sed -e "s/^\#\*\([ ]+soft[ ]+core\)[0-9][0-9]*$/\*\1 unlimited/" limits.conf
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed command find and replace in file and overwrite file doesnt work, it empties the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties)

Comment: @alfasin: the suggested duplicate is a common related problem, but is not the cause of the trouble with this `sed` command.  The problem here is that the regex didn't match the input, not that the input file was clobbered (as in the proposed duplicate).

Answer (score 5):

#### Mechanics of `sed`

There are a variety of issues:

1. You don't need the backslash in front of the `#`, nor in front of the `*` in the replacement text.  They don't do much harm, but they are not necessary.
2. You need to allow for spaces between `core` and the number.
3. You didn't allow for blanks and tabs in the file.
4. You didn't allow for trailing white space on the line (which might not matter).
5. You didn't explicitly enable extended regular expressions, and you did use the old-style `\(…\)` capturing notation, but that means `+` has no special meaning.
6. You didn't modify the file in place with the `-i` option (which is fine while you're getting the `sed` command correct).

You should be able to use (GNU `sed`):

```
sed -r -e "s/^#\*([[:space:]]+soft[[:space:]]+core)[[:space:]]+[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]]*$/\*\1 unlimited/" limits.conf
```

The `[[:space:]]` notation recognizes all sorts of white space (including newlines, etc); you could also use `[[:blank:]]` which only recognizes blanks and tabs if you prefer.

You could also use the old-style notation:

```
sed -e "s/^#\*\([[:space:]]\{1,\}soft[[:space:]]\{1,\}core\)[[:space:]]\{1,\}[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]]*$/*\1 unlimited/" limits.conf
```

If you want to preserve the white space between `core` and the number, you can:

```
sed -e "s/^#\*\([[:space:]]\{1,\}soft[[:space:]]\{1,\}core[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]]*$/*\1unlimited/" limits.conf
```

The close for the capture is moved, and there's no need to add a space in the replacement string.

#### Be cautious when modifying the system file

Note that you should be very careful when you are sure your script is ready to modify the production file.  I usually create a new file, check it, then copy the old file to a date/time-stamped file name, and copy the new file over the original.  Alternatively, use a suffix with `-i`, probably with date/time again.

```
sed -i .$(date +'%Y%m%d.%H%M%S') -e "s/^#\*\([[:space:]]\{1,\}soft[[:space:]]\{1,\}core[[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[0-9][0-9]*[[:space:]]*$/*\1unlimited/" limits.conf
```

The advantage of that format (which is based on ISO 8601:2004) is that successive files sort into date order without any special sorting options.  You can add punctuation into the date/time format if you wish.

Either way, if the new file gives problems, you've got (a copy of) the original which you can put back so that the system is running again smoothly as quickly as is reasonably feasible.

Comment: +1, but you might want to mention the ill-advised nature of the request. This sort of change to a security related file should probably not be done this way.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: yes, I wondered about that.  I did partially mention it with bullet 6, but debated whether to extend that.  I'll make an addition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information Jonathan.  I change the pattern after core to [0-z][-z] to handle the case if the original value is non-numeric, e.g. it is also 'unlimited', but is just commented out.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/^#.*soft.*core/ {sub(/^#/,"");sub(/0$/,"unlimited")}1' file
*               soft    core           unlimited
```

Comment: be carrefull on other line that are commented but not about `soft ... core` subject