# sed: make changes in the same file on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, replace, sed

I use `sed` on Windows (actually under GitBash) and [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties) doesn't work.

```
$ sed -ibak 's/a/b/g' test1
sed: preserving permissions for `./sed004224': Permission denied
```

Is there any another approach to do this (or maybe fix this)? 
(I know about using perl, and we can move a result file to replace source one.)

**UPD 1**
It works when I run GitBush "as Administrator". Actually logged Windows user is Admin too.

Comment: It's the same behavior. ;)

Comment: try this seq 10 | sed 's/$/ Love/' to see is sed problem or test1 permissions

Comment: What does `seq` mean? But.. Yeah, this command exists in unix. You know, I don't have it on Windows. And there ain't specific permissions. I suppose there is a permission problem because process and file system.

Comment: seq 10 will print nums 1..10

Comment: Is the permissions problem with the sed command or with the test1 file? I would not use the -i option to "edit in place". If the script fails your input file is trashed and it's difficult to recover from. It's trivial to do the same thing without using that option as well.

Comment: You know I've tried this but run GitBush "as Administrator" and it works. File `test1` - usual file w/o specific permissions. I confused what is a problem...

Comment: > If the script fails your input file is trashed and it's difficult to recover from
- Totally agree. :)

Comment: I know the thread is old, but I just had the same problem under Windows. The fix was to just remove the Read-only flag of the directory containing the file(s)...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably problem is with permissions of file test1, so solution will be simple to change it to be writable, or excluding -i option and redirecting to new file in writable folder
sed 's/a/b/g' test1 >somepath/newfile

Comment: Yeah, I know we can write output to some file but looking working with the same file.