# Linux replace a word in all files

Tags: linux

I am using Linux CentOS. I have many folders inside my `www` directory and there are a lot of files inside those folders. I would like to change in those files:

> www.mysite.com

to

> www.myNewSite.com

Is there a way to run q command and that will replace all?

Comment: This is a tad beyond my level of script-fu but take a look at the sed command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties

Comment: Also, please do remember to accept your answers (all of them) if they have given you satisfactory answers (by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answers), it would be helpful to the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed --in-place 's/www.mysite.com/www.myNewSite.com/g' *.php
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` command. Below is the command. I tested and seems working.

```
[chatar@/Users/chatar]$  find test -name '*.php' 
test/folder1/one.php
test/folder1/two.php
test/folder2/four.php
test/folder2/three.php
[chatar@/Users/chatar]$  find test -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep www {} \;
www.mysite.com 
www.mysite.com 
www.mysite.com 
www.mysite.com 
[chatar@/Users/chatar]$  find test -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i -e 's/mysite/myNewSite/g' {} \;
[chatar@/Users/chatar]$  find test -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep www {} \;
www.myNewSite.com 
www.myNewSite.com 
www.myNewSite.com 
www.myNewSite.com 
[chatar@/Users/chatar]$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) on-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's/www\.mysite\.com/www.myNewSite.com/g' *.php
```

If you want to keep copies of the original files (with `.bak` extensions), use:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/www\.mysite\.com/www.myNewSite.com/g' *.php
```