# Add max_allowed_packet to my.cnf in vagrant environment

Tags: bash, vagrantfile, my.cnf, vagrant-provision

So I have a box that includes a mysqldump file executed at provision. The problem now is that I need to increase the max_allowed_packet variable before execute this script.

How can I do something like:

```
max_allowed_packet = 128M >> /etc/my.cnf
```

but rather than at the EOF do it after the `[mysqld]` section

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's|\[mysqld\]|&\nmax_allowed_packet = 128M|' /etc/my.cnf
```

---

> `-i`: edit file "in place"
>
> `&`: refer to that portion which matched
>
> `\n`: new line

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus. You sollution outputs but didn't write. With your hint, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties#answer-5171935 and now I'm done

Comment: I suppose you do not use GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cyrus

```
sed -i.bak 's|\[mysqld\]|&\nmax_allowed_packet = 128M|' /etc/my.cnf
```