# How to remove time date stamp from string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

Hello sed/awk/bash experts,

I have thousands of certs to report on and I want to remove the time:

```
www.bob.com  | Jul 28 19:22:38 2015   | Jul 27 19:22:38 2017
```

How can I (easily) remove 19:22:38 & 19:22:38 so I just have:

```
www.bob.com  | Jul 28 2015 | Jul 27 2017
```

Comment: Is the time 19:22:38 common in every certs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit the file in place rather than just outputting to the screen, use a modified version of [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava)'s command:

```
sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[[:blank:]]+//g' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

It also has the added benefit of not wiping your original file should `sed` fail. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174368/1054571).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an older version of sed you could try the following:

```
$ echo "www.bob.com  | Jul 28 19:22:38 2015   | Jul 27 19:22:38 2017" | sed 's/\([a-zA-Z]*[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*\)[0-9:]*\([ ]*[0-9]*\)/\1\2/g'
www.bob.com  | Jul 28  2015   | Jul 27  2017
```

Or perhaps to just remove the time, you could instead use:

```
echo "www.bob.com  | Jul 28 19:22:38 2015   | Jul 27 19:22:38 2017" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]//g'
www.bob.com  | Jul 28  2015   | Jul 27  2017
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$5=""; $10=""; print}' file
www.bob.com | Jul 28  2015 | Jul 27  2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[[:blank:]]+//g' file

www.bob.com  | Jul 28 2015   | Jul 27 2017
```