# Transforming csv file headers

Tags: csv

I have a csv file with more number of headers. Each time I am getting this file, I wish to change the name of the headers.

Sample File:

```
 Name    Price .....
 Cat     5000
 Dog     8000
```

I wish to change the header name "Price" to "Rate". I can't do it manually each time. Is there any automation tool available so that i can feed in the required changes and the file which will inturn return the file after the applied changes.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't even started. It is achievable by writing code in any languages. But i would like to know is there any automation tool is existing.

Comment: Depends on the Plattform you are using. These two might help: 
on Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties
on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell