# removing a character from a file with sed leads to an empty file

Tags: sed

I am on a mac and I am trying to set up a cron task to remove all instances of the '#' from my /etc/hosts file

I use this command:

`sed 's/\#//g' /etc/hosts`

which seems to work fine, but when I do this to output it to replace the content in /etc/hosts:

`sed 's/\#//g' /etc/hosts > /etc/hosts`

the /etc/hosts file ends up being empty. Why is it ending up empty?

Comment: Dupe of [Find and replace in file and overwrite file doesn't work, it empties the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901)

Comment: or [How can I use a file in a command and redirect output to the same file without truncating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6696842/3266847)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6696877/390913