# Sed gives "sed: 1: "tsunit.js": undefined label 'sunit.js'"

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

Short questing, why does this line

```
sed -i '1s/^/#!\/usr\/bin\/env node\n/' tsunit.js;\
```

Give me this error

```
sed: 1: "tsunit.js": undefined label 'sunit.js'
```

in a Makefile, if relevant.

I’m on a Mac.

Comment: you can use another separator in `s` if  there is already `/(slash)`, like `sed 's@/foo/bar/blah@replacement@g' file `  save a lot of escape and make it readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variations of sed between OSX and GNU/Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/variations-of-sed-between-osx-and-gnu-linux)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the Apple man page for `sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), the `-i` option takes a required argument specifying the file extension for the backup file.  As a result, assuming that you are on a Mac or similar, `sed` believes that you intended `'1s/^/#!\/usr\/bin\/env node\n/'` to be the file extension of the backup.  It then interprets `tsunit.js` as a `sed` command.  the leading `t` tells sed to branch to the label `sunit.js` which, of course, doesn't exist.  Hence the error message.

The solution is:

```
sed -i '.bak' '1s/^/#!\/usr\/bin\/env node\n/' tsunit.js
```

Or, if you really do not want a backup:

```
sed -i '' '1s/^/#!\/usr\/bin\/env node\n/' tsunit.js
```

Comment: Thank you for the very well formulated, in depth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it looks like you're inserting a line. sed has more commands than `s`

```
sed -i "" '1i\
#!/usr/bin/env node' tsunit.js
```

Comment: +1 because it is so easy to forget that sed has other commands.