# How to prefix (or modify) a certain line in a file in Bash on OSX

Tags: macos, bash

Using the terminal (in OSX), how do I modify a specific line of a file?

e.g. I have a javascript file and want to comment out line 300 by prepending `//`

Comment: Don't put solutions in your question; if you use something substantially different from the accepted answer, add an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `sed`:

```
sed -i '300s%^%//%' myfilename.js
```

Some versions of `sed` (such as the BSD version that ships with Mac OS X), require an explicit argument for `-i`. If you don't want a backup, use the empty string.

```
sed -i "" '300s%^%//%' myfilename.js
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't actually work for me: `command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: @AshleyCoolman: It definitely does work. Are you sure you typed it exactly? And did you get an error message?

Comment: Hm `sed -i '1679s%^%//%' angular-protractor.d.ts` gets me `sed: 1: "angular-protractor.d.ts": command a expects \ followed by text`

Comment: Hmm, which versioni of "sed" are you using?

Comment: Ah I should of mentioned I'm on OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/variations-of-sed-between-osx-and-gnu-linux

Comment: Ok thanks mate - san you add the a version for OSX with `-e` to your answer?

Comment: The proper solution is to provide `-i` with an explicit argument; it's not clear why adding `-e` works, but a comment in the linked question indicates that it does not always work.