# Append/replace string to a line using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to parse a file test.txt and append "https://" to the following string within the file:

```
 "1234.def.efj.abcd-1.nopqrs.com"
```

Note: the string has white space and the quotes at the beginning and end. Also def, efj, and nopqrs.com are static and won't change.

I am trying to accomplish this via sed. So far I have:

```
sed -e 's#^\s*[\"][0-9]+[\.]def[\.]efj[\.][a-z]+[\-][a-z]+[\-][0-9][\.]nopqrs[\.]com$#\s+[\"]https[\:][\/][\/][0-9]+[\.]def[\.]efj[\.][a-z]+[\-][a-z]+[\-][0-9][\.]nopqrs[\.]com#g' test.txt
```

When I run that command I just get the file output without the change.
I have gone through other sed posts and can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my expression. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work :

```
sed -i 's#"\([^"]*\.nopqrs\.com\)"#"https://\1"#g' file.txt
```

**Explanation :**

- `sed -i` : inplace editing. `sed` will update `file.txt` accordingly. [Note that the behaviour and syntax is implementation specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/i-need-my-sed-i-command-for-in-place-editing-to-work-with-both-gnu-sed-and-bsd).
- `"\([^"]*\.nopqrs\.com\)"` :

  - `[^"]*\.nopqrs\.com`: we look for any number of characters that are not quotes, followed by `.nopqrs.com`
  - `\( ... \)` : syntax for sed to create a capture group with the content matched by the expression between the parenthesis
- `\1` : we display the content of the first capture group

Comment: Be sure to check which implementation of `sed` you are using; they differ as to whether `-i` (if supported at all) requires an argument or not.

Comment: That's a bit over-quoted.  You don't need to escape the double quotes (`"`) because the appear inside single quotes (which protects them from interpretation by the shell) and they are not special to `sed`.  It still works; it's just harder to read than it needs to be.

Comment: I don't understand why people are so eager to use `-i` in  their answers - chances are the OP doesn't know what it does and when they go to test your answer they accidentally wreck their input file! Let the OP add `-i` on their own later if they want it.