# Find and replace key word for all files (Mac OS)

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace the word `willow` with `oak` throughout my code.
This change needs to be made to multiple files at different levels.

I have attempted to use the answers from:
[How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string-with-awk-or-sed)

Especially,
`grep -rl willow . | xargs sed -i -e '' 's/willow/oak/g'`

---

As I am using a Mac (from: [sed -i command for in-place editing to work with both GNU sed and BSD/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320564/sed-i-command-for-in-place-editing-to-work-with-both-gnu-sed-and-bsd-osx)), I have used the extra `-e ''` commands. However, I am getting

`s/willow/oak/g: No such file or directory`

---

I have also tried:

`grep -rl willow . | xargs sed -i '' 's/willow/oak/g'`

which (due to the OS) gave:
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence.

---

How can I recursively go through all the files in different dictionaries on a Mac to replace all instances of willow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> grep -rl willow . | xargs sed -i -e '' 's/willow/oak/g'
> ```
>
> I have used the extra -e '' commands.

You have misread or misinterpreted the answers from which you got that idea, creating an   additional problem instead of solving one.  With that command, not only does MacOS `sed` interpret the `-e` as the extension for backup files and `'s/willow/oak/g'` as an input file name, but it also interprets `''` as a (zero-length) file name.  The latter is what your error message is about.

> I have also tried:
>
> ```
> grep -rl willow . | xargs sed -i '' 's/willow/oak/g'
> ```

Per [its manual page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/sed/), if you use the `-i` or `-f` option with Mac `sed` then you *must* use `-e` if you want to specify a command via the command line.  That is, you want this:

```
grep -rl willow . | xargs sed -i '' -e 's/willow/oak/g'
```

That specifies an empty backup extension for `-i`, thus suppressing the generation of backup files, and specifies a `sed` command on the command line via `-e`.